# iMovie stopped exporting

Tags: itunes, video, ipod-touch, imovie, video-editing

I've been using/learning iMovie in order to create online classes for my students because of COVID19. Everything has been working fine until this morning.

iMovie just won't export a file.

I've created and exported about 30 videos thus far and I understand the basics. But now, when I select all the clips in a project and select the "Share - File..." option and hit "OK", nothing happens. No error messages, nothing. The little pie-chart progress indicator flashes for a fraction of a second before disappearing for good. The application doesn't bug or freeze (as I can keep working on the video or move to other projects), it just doesn't export the file.

I also can't export any of the videos it previously exported in the last few days and weeks. Nor will it export and brand new video.

I tried deleting the preferences: didn't solve anything.

I'm on 10.13 and iMovie 10.1.6 (and I can't upgrade).

Thanks.

P.S. The only change I made to the computer since yesterday is that I installed iOS 14 on my ipod touch. I had to use the MobileDeviceUpdater in order for iTunes to recognize my ipod touch.  I can't imagine why it would change anything for iMovie, but nothing else changed.

Comment: I wonder if it is running out of disk space or you have a poisoned cache? I would check disk space and use a cleaner program like Onyx. The other thing would be to check console.app for anything with "imovie" in it. Sometimes lack of errors just means lack of visible errors. there *might* be something in a log somewhere and console.app could find that for you.

Comment: You were right: there was an error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.Compressor.CompressorKit.ErrorDomain error -1.)"

Comment: Try booting into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) (which clears out cache files & other oddities) and see if the exports work as expected.

Comment: I tried. Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: I found the solution. For those interested, you'll find it in this Apple Discussion thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251828217

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and reopening iMove, then export again. This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome on AD: have look at the Tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour Although the OP doesnt clearly state it, it seems very likely he has tried to close and reopen iMovie. Therefore this does not seem to me like a useful answer.